# genymotion ARM translation: "…/lib/arm/libndk.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40

Tags: android-ndk, android-emulator

Here is [full code](https://github.com/roroco/android-ndk-tutorial-code-read-only/tree/unexpected-e-machine), when I try android jni sample, I get `has unexpected e_machine`, the full steps are:

- `$ /media/roroco/disk750/adr/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-buil`
- in project, new android application, and run it

and get following output

```
Process: com.mamlambo.sample.ndk1, PID: 5560
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.mamlambo.sample.ndk1-1/lib/arm/libndk1.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
            at com.mamlambo.sample.ndk1.AndroidNDK1SampleActivity.<clinit>(AndroidNDK1SampleActivity.java:35)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
```

Answer (score 5):

I find the solution, the reason is I use genymotion and install genymotion armtranslation, the armtranslation has bug, so I should build c to x86 device, the steps are:

- create jni/Application.mk, write "APP_ABI := x86 armeabi armeabi-v7a"
- ndk-build
- debug app in genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio for Mac i get a similar error when i build the release version of the app and run it on Genymotion with ARM translation. `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/<appname>/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40`

1. I solved the issue by following steps :
2. Right click the project name
3. Choose **Options**
4. Choose **Build**
5. Choose **Android Build**
6. Change the **Configuration** to **Release(Active)**
7. Go to the **Advanced** tab and add the **x86** under **Supported ABIs**